# Disable Swipe left and right on CarouselView when swiping down Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

First of all I am working on a Xamarin PCL project using Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh to refresh the content on my pages that happen to be in a CarouselView, but I have found that it is nearly impossible to pull down and not swipe left or right to the next page. Is there a way I could disable or block the left to right swiping when the page begins to pull down? I am struggling even trying to come up with a method to do this.

Comment: Would Mr. Gestures help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a carouselviewpage renderer perhaps and than on the ViewDidLoad you could do

```
foreach (var g in this.View.GestureRecognizers)
            g.ShouldBegin = recognizer => false;
```

--> this removes all gesture recognizers on your carouspage